# Starting Firefox with a specified profile from the dock (Mac OS X)

Tags: macos, firefox, firefox-profile

I have different Firefox profiles for each version I have installed on my system and I know I can specify the profile name I want to use like this:

```
/Applications/Minefield.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin -P minefield
```

Is it possible to create a dock icon or alias with additional parameters (just like in [this article](http://lifehacker.com/231646/geek-to-live--manage-multiple-firefox-profiles) with shortcuts on windows)? That way I could have as many profiles as I want and wouldn't see the profile manager everytime I start the browser.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a bit more work to do this on mac but this is what you want:

[Managing Multiple Firefox Profiles in OS X](http://web.archive.org/web/20100717003457/http://spf13.com/feature/managing-firefox-profiles-os-x) (via [Internet Archive WayBackMachine](http://archive.org/web/))

The custom Firefox icons are still available from [Gnome-Look.org](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Firefox+Icons?content=47617)

Comment: Thanks, it works. The only thing I don't like is that I have two icons on my dock now. One for the launcher and one for the app itself.

Answer (score 7):

Script Editor based solution was quite slow for me, so I looked for an alternative.

I ended up creating an application bundle with a bash script inside - see details at [Using Firefox profiles on Mac OS X](http://asqueella.blogspot.com/2010/01/using-firefox-profiles-on-mac-os-x.html).

Comment: I suggest `open -a Firefox.app --args [...]` as it's more robust (installation path, binary name).

Comment: @DanielBeck: Thanks for the tip! Somehow I missed it when you posted it. Note to other readers: you will need the -n flag (as in `open -n -a Firefox.app --args -no-remote -P ...`) to open multiple instances, as by default `open` focuses the existing application.

Comment: This non-script alternative still works in Mavericks 10.9.1 and, when coupled with the custom icons mentioned in the other answer, is an especially copacetic solution.

Comment: Very relevant answer: https://superuser.com/a/236446/567432 It's about how to launch an app with command line arguments (in general), and it so happens the Firefox Profile Manager is the example used. I tested it and it works.

Comment: It is broken on 10.15. Profile window opens but no urls may be opened from other apps https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1653218

Comment: That bug is not confirmed yet and it looks more like a troubleshooting session...

Answer (score 6):

Here in the future I run multiple Firefoxes, each with unique Dock icons, app names, and unique & separate user profiles.

#### My motivations

- to have multiple Gmail, Twitter, GitHub etc. accounts simultaneously logged-in
- to group websites by concept: coding, comms, news, finance, video, music
- to label them by concept /Applications and the tab-switcher, and provide unique visual identity with different MacOS .icns file
- to bucket my cookie exposure, in order to avoid over-sharing my movements about the internet with le Goog, social media, and advert tracking firms

#### How I did it

**1. Copy Firefox** (bulky at ~360MB per copy, I know, but haven't found another viable option, see below)

- Duplicate `/Applications/Firefox.app` using `Cmd-D` or `sudo cp -r ...`
- Rename the new app folder from `Firefox copy.app` to whatever, `FF Proxied.app` in my case

**2. Give your FF copy a new visual identity**

- Change the icon by right-clicking `FF Proxied.app` and clicking `Get Info`, then drag your new icon onto the Firefox icon, replacing it. Close the Get Info dialog
- You can create a `.icns` file using the Python console script [`generate-iconset`](https://github.com/retifrav/generate-iconset) made by [retif](https://superuser.com/users/682702/retif). Be sure to start from a **square** PNG image; I use GIMP to make the background transparent by adding an alpha channel.
- Change the app label (displayed in macOS's menubar) by editing `FF Proxied.app/Contents/Resources/en.lproj/InfoPlist.strings` and changing its contents from `CFBundleName = "Firefox";` to `CFBundleName = "FF Proxied";`

**3. Give your FF copy its own user profile**

- I `mkdir` mine under ~/ff_profiles, and you may want to create a similar top-level folder for your FF profiles

  - `mkdir ~/ff_profiles/proxied` (for example)
- Start `FF Proxied` in Profile Manager, like so-

  ```
  $ /Applications/FF\ Proxied.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox --ProfileManager
  ```
- Once in Profile Manager dialog-

  - click `Create Profile...`
  - click `Continue`
  - name the profile whatever
  - click `Choose Folder...`
  - navigate to the folder you just `mkdir`'d, then click `Open`
  - click `Done`
  - Back in the Profile dialog, ensure the profile you just created is highlighted, and that you've checked the checkbox `[X] Use the selected profile without asking at startup`
  - now click `Exit`

**4. Add your new FF copy to the Dock**

- in Finder, navigate to `FF Proxied` (or whatever you named yours), and drag it onto the Dock

**5. Test it**

- click your "new app" on the Dock

#### Upsides

- separate app instances
- separate visual identities (icons, labels)
- provides a fairly durable and concept-limited container for groups of websites
- I no longer hunt for open tabs anymore (yes I used the `switch to tab` feature before this, but that doesn't solve the concept-grouping need)
- better than all the tab and window organizer extensions I've tried on both FF and Chrome

#### Downsides

- more disk space consumed
- each copy will prompt you update when new versions come (but each copy does index update only its own copy)
- the overhead of running multiple FF instances
- you have to set up preferences from scratch for each FF copy

  - I tried copying prefs folders, but they appear to have baked in whatever path they were created on, annoyingly

#### Other options I tried

- Platypus: no joy; it's meant for CLI scripts, not GUI apps
- Script Editor: same experience as @Nickolay ([above](https://superuser.com/a/102460))
- Firefox's [Multi-Account Containers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/multi-account-containers/?utm_source=addons.mozilla.org) extension? Not in my experience, because-

  - a domain name can belong only to a single container
  - therefore having several gmail.com's open doesn't work very well
  - opening new tabs for a container is awkward
  - the extension doesn't seem to manage cookie separation very well, and sometimes I find that a site I logged into on one tab, will not be logged in when I visit the same site in a new tab
- Symlinking all but the menubar label file (`FF Coding.app/Contents/Resources/en.lproj/InfoPlist.strings`)

  - This runs into a weird bug where Firefox cannot access files under symlinked folders, e.g. .../Content/Resources/omni.ja (zipfile archive apparently containing Firefox's JS chrome code)
  - see [my attempt at a Firefox symlinker script here](https://gist.github.com/Kevin-Prichard/cb6d95b6684fec585d5160f96c9605a0)
  - If the symlink bug was fixed, symlinked clones of Firefox would mainly cost the diskspace for the .icns file, folders & symlinks, and `InfoPlist.strings`

All corrections & suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried the Automator bundle way? I like Firefox (and in fact *all* my non-system apps) managed by homebrew, and having to make an exception would be another downside of your solution. The Automator one comes closest for me but so far I  don't know how to set a distinct icon that will persist in *all* relevant places even when it's running so I can easily switch to it. This is turning out to be the least tractable problem with the Mac UI since I switched from Linux last year :-(

Comment: @q.undertow, thank you for the suggestion, I hadn't looked very far at other macOS solutions.  I wonder if it's possible to substitute a file on launch, such as the icon container.  I do realize my approach is arduous, and not many will adopt it.  I'll take a look at Automator and and AppleScript, see if they have ways around launching multiple copies of an app, customized.

Comment: @Kevin-Prichard:  Thank you so much!  I just used your steps and it worked perfectly for me.  I have to login to a network switch multiple times a day that has a bad self-signed certificate.  The admin hasn't prioritized the issue and I get logged out after 10 minutes of activity.  This is totally worth the headache for the time saved for this one site.