# Starting Firefox with a specified profile, crashes when browser tried to access microphone or camera

Tags: macos, firefox, microphone, camera, firefox-profile

Sorry this is probably a very niche bug.

I created two different applications to launch Firefox with different profiles and have them use different icons for easy app switching.

I followed the steps from [this tutorial](http://asqueella.blogspot.com/2010/01/using-firefox-profiles-on-mac-os-x.html) that I found on [this superuser question](https://superuser.com/questions/75271/starting-firefox-with-a-specified-profile-from-the-dock-mac-os-x) to achieve it.

Everything works great, except Firefox will crash when websites trying to access the Microphone or Camera try to gain permission.

I can post the error log if its helpful but I'm hoping its just a simple file permissions fix that will solve the problem. Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Does firefox not crash when not using multiple profiles? Does it only crash when firefox of both profiles are running? Are you running the last firefox version?

Comment: Yes it is the latest version of firefox. It happens regardless of if multiple profiles are running. If I open firefox through the app with the launcher script, it will crash in this case.