# self-closing applescript

Tags: applescript, shell-script

so I'm totally new to applescript..

basically I want my applescript.app to run a shell script then exit

`do shell script "/usr/local/groovy/bin/groovyConsole"`

the above script opens groovyConsole just fine, but my applescript.app is still running - I want it to close itself after it runs the shell script....

any help would be great!

Answer (score 3):

You can have the shell run a program “in the background” (by appending `&`), but *do shell script* will still wait until every process has closed any instances of the file descriptors it opened for the program’s stdout and stderr. Redirecting them will suffice.

```
do shell script "/usr/local/groovy/bin/groovyConsole >/dev/null 2>&1 &"
```

Comment: I'm not sure output redirection is necessary -- [sometimes](http://superuser.com/questions/16750/how-can-i-run-an-application-with-command-line-arguments-in-mac-os/236446#236446) it works without.

Comment: @Daniel: It is required for the general case. It is not required for your specific example because *open* (actually LaunchServices) does the work of “backgrounding” and making sure the stdout and stderr of the processes it ultimately leaves running are sent elsewhere (to the per-user *launchd* in 10.6).

Comment: I was referring to my first snippet, calling the binary directly. `open` is very different, true. I just don't see what's wrong with Trevor's answer.

Comment: @Daniel: Your first snippet uses Automator; its *Run Shell Script* does not do the same “wait for all instances of stdout/stderr pipes to close” thing that AppleScript’s *do shell script* does. Example: `do shell script "sleep 5 &"` always takes 5 seconds to return, but `do shell script "sleep 5 >/dev/null 2>&1 &"` always returns as quickly as possible. The shell exits and *sleep* runs in the background in both cases; however, in the first case, *sleep* has inherited the fds against which *do shell script* is waiting. Trevor’s answer may work, but it depends on the behavior of *groovyConsole*.

Comment: That's good to know. Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought, try adding an ampersand sign to the end of the script.

```
do shell script "/usr/local/groovy/bin/groovyConsole &"
```

It backgrounds the commands and will return you to a prompt (when at a command line). It might just make the Applescript app finish.

Good luck!