# how to set a permanent google chrome flag?

Tags: macos, google-chrome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I run an application with command line arguments in Mac OS](https://superuser.com/questions/16750/how-can-i-run-an-application-with-command-line-arguments-in-mac-os)

I'm trying to make this flag run every time I launch Google Chrome on OSX:
--allow-outdated-plugins

It works with the terminal, but I need it to be default with no need for the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

[This script](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/chrome/_CnkF0tj6xk/yynqSTnTNnUJ) (quoted below) worked for me. No need for terminal whatsoever:

> **How to fix Adobe Flash issue on Mac OS X 10.5.8 with
>   allow-outdated-plugins switch and restore Chrome functionality**
>   (step-by-step screen shots included):
>
> **Step 1.** In Finder goto the Finder pull-down menu -> Services -> Script
>   Editor -> Make New AppleScript
>
> **Step 2.** Copy/Paste the following into Script Editor:

```
do shell script "/Applications/Google\\
Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\\ Chrome --allow-outdated-plugins &
killall ChromeScript.app"
```

> **Step 3.** Goto File -> Save As -> **FILENAME: ChromeScript (File Format:
>   select "Application"; Options: make sure only "Run Only" is checked)
>
> **BE SURE TO NAME YOUR FILE ChromeScript FOR THE APPLESCRIPT TO WORK CORRECTLY
>
> From now on you will use your new ChromeScript app to open Chrome. You
>   can also replace your "old" Chrome icon in your launch bar with the
>   new script for convenience. Remember to manually update your plugins
>   once in a while because Chrome will no longer do it automatically.

Could you tell me how you run terminal though? It did not work no matter how I ran commands, so I'm just curious.