# MacOS Start FireFox via CommandLine in 32 bit

Tags: macos, firefox, command-line, automator, command-line-arguments

Firefox can be startet via Commandline

[How can I run an application with command line arguments in Mac OS](https://superuser.com/questions/16750/how-can-i-run-an-application-with-command-line-arguments-in-mac-os)

Is there an argument to make it start in 32 bit ?

I know i could select it via finder, but thats no option for my problem

I have solved a similar problem for chrome by creating an Automator "Launcher" which start Chrome with deactivated flash, but for that I need to know whether there is a command line argument to set 32bit.

Maybe by changing systems settings by "default" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`arch -i386 /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin` should do the trick in Terminal.

You could then pack that into an AppleScript of some kind.

Answer (score 1):

A solution I still have to test

```
#!/bin/bash

# Check to see if Firefox exists
if
 ls -la /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/Resources

then

# Set the architecture preference order to 32-bit first
defaults write /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/Info "LSArchitecturePriority" '(i386,   "x86_64")'

# Making sure the permissions on the Info.plist are correct
chmod -R 775 /Applications/Firefox.app/

else
echo "Firefox is not installed"

fi
```

Comment: sadly not really working althoguh my research showed that it is the right approach to use LSArchitecturePriority

Comment: I'd disagree -- modifying an application bundle is a bad idea. For example, it'll invalidate the app's code signature.

Comment: you maybe right on that, its not working properly anyway ill try the other answer